# Can parent and child views obtain the motion event simultaneously in Android?

Tags: android, events, motion

In the main activity, there is a parent view and a child view.

I need to obtain the motion event in both views simultaneously. Is it possible to do that ?

Currently, I can only intercept the motion event in the child view. Parent view receives nothing.

The main task is both of them can get the motion events at the same time. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ? I have the same problem, a child view has some custom handling for onDown and onUp, and now I want to add a fling detector on the root view, but one eats up the other depending on the return value of onTouch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these methods depending on what you are trying to do:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand the second approach. Would you please explain it ?

Comment: Override that method.  It is the one that actually dispatches a touch event to the children.  Thus you will be processing the events before they are sent to the children.